# How eigenvalues change when row is multiplied by a constant?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose I have an $n\times n$ real matrix $M$, not necessarily symmetric. Now I take a row $1 \le i \le n$ of this matrix, and I multiply it by a constant real $c$.

Is there a way to understand the effects of the value of $c$ on the eigenvalues of the modified matrix in general?

Comment: Maybe that's clear anyway, but the dependence on the coefficients is continuous. Thus if $c$ is close to one the eigenvalues won't change much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fear that even for low dim the relation will be utterly complicated.

If $B=DA$ with $D=diag(1,1,\cdots,c,\cdots,1)$ then $Bx=DAx=\lambda Dx$

but $Dx=(x_1,\cdots,cx_i,\cdots,x_n)$ has nothing to do with $x$ so eigenspaces of $A$ and $B$ will be completely different.

You can have fun with this *nice* matrix 
$\begin{bmatrix}1& 4& 5& 2\\5& 6& 1& 5\\ 4& 1& 4& 4\\ 3& 2& 3& 2\end{bmatrix}$ it has eigenvalues $\{-1,-3,4,-13\}$

Try to multiply a row by $-1$ or $2$ and you will see how different the eigenvalues become (some are not even real anymore).

---

Here is for instance a $2\times2$ example.

$A=\begin{bmatrix}2&2\\-1&5\end{bmatrix}$ with eigenvalues $\{3,4\}$

Let's multiply first row by $c$, then eigenvalues are now $\begin{cases}c+\frac 52+\frac 12\sqrt{4c^2-28c+25}\\ c+\frac 52-\frac 12\sqrt{4c^2-28c+25}\end{cases}$

We cannot call this some "easy relation", and this is just dimension $2$.

Comment: Oh it's way more complicated than I thought. I'm trying to understand the effect of increasing the velocity along a coordinate in a system of ordinary differential equations. Does it change the stability of fixed points?

Comment: Anyway your counterexample answers my question.

Comment: may I ask how you came by this matrix?

Comment: I just searched the internet for "integer matrix with integer eigenvalues".

Comment: If you only multiply by a constant (or even a constant function) along one coordinate  (it is a single column in your system?) and if you have a system of differential equations, then you can check the Wronskian solution, as an integral formula this parameter comes out of the integral. @zwim

Answer (score 1):

Very complicated.

Just check this example:

let be  $A = \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 2 \\ 5 & 4 \end{bmatrix} $, with eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$, which are the solution of

$0=\det(A-\lambda I) = x^2-7x+2$

and now check 
$A = \begin{bmatrix} 3\alpha & 2\alpha \\ 5 & 4 \end{bmatrix} $ with characteristic polynomial 
$0=\det(\begin{bmatrix} 3\alpha & 2\alpha \\ 5 & 4 \end{bmatrix}-\lambda I) = x^2-(4+3\alpha)x+2\alpha$

there is no relation between those two equations (relations of shared roots, with a first look)